# Do we need to create different adapter for each activity on Xamarin?

Tags: c#, android, json, xamarin, adapter

Im working on an android project on Xamarin, i had the main page running and i want to ListViewItemOnClick each of the menu. The main activity and the clicked-menu activity are using the same data from the Entry. The question is should i create different adapter for each avtivities?

Comment: Cannot understand your question, could you provide a little more information to be able to help you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a clear question. Still I would like to give you some guidelines to use Adapters.

Basically, Adapters help Activities to bind datacollections to UI. They are inherited from `BaseAdaptor` class. Adapter is a per datacollection thing not a per activity thing. One Adapter can server for many Activities. For example, if you have an Adapter to read emails called `EmailAdapter`, you can use it is `MainActivity.cs` as well as any other Activities.

You must be aware of implementing the abstract methods from BaseAdapter, when you are implementing `GetView` you should provide a view, for which you define it as a Layout which can be used to initiate ListViews in any activity.

Eg : Consider You have 2 activities
`MainActivity.cs` and `MailActivity.cs` you need to show emails in both activities coming from same datasource. So create a layout called `EmailItem.xml` which will look similar to

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ContactImage"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_margin="5dp" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ContactName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Create an Adapter called `EmailAdapter`

```
public class EmailAdapter : BaseAdapter
{
    List<Contact> _contactList;
    Activity _activity;

    public ContactsAdapter (Activity activity)
        {
            _activity = activity;
            FillEmail ();
        }

    void FillEmail ()
    {
        //Logic to fill email
    }

    class Email
    {
        public long Id { get; set; }
        public string DisplayName{ get; set; }
    }
}
```

and when you implement `BaseAdapter` you have to implement `GetView`where you have to define a view and return it. So assign view to the layout you created

```
var view = convertView ?? _activity.LayoutInflater.Inflate (
        Resource.Layout.EmailItem, parent, false);
```

Now in your `OnCreate()` of each activities call

```
var emailAdapter = new EmailAdapter (this);
var emailView = FindViewById<ListView> (Resource.Id.EmailView);
emailView.Adapter = contactsAdapter;
```

Here `EmailView` can be a layout per activity.

Comment: Wow you really enlighten me up, but im almost there. So, say i have 2 activities MainActivity.cs and Next.cs, i have the getview for the MainActivity.cs inside the adapter and also the MainActivity.axml layout, i already created the Next.cs and Next.axml, based on what you suggested i should create a getview for Next.cs inside the adapter i already have the same as MainActivity.cs is using?

Comment: `GetView` has to implemeted for `EmailAdapter` because its an abstract method of `BaseAdapter`. `GetView` is "per Adapter" thing. Not a "per Activity" thing.

Comment: Ok, in my case i have this datacollection, can i have more than one adapter (although both of them are binding the same datacollection)? because according to you one `GetView` is only for one adapter cause its a "Per Adapter" thing, while i'm attempting to show different kind of layout/UI for both `MainActivity.cs` and `MailActivity.cs`//

And if i can, is it possible to have 2 `baseadaptor`s in the code or one of them cant have it?

Comment: You are saying "attempting to show different kind of layout/UI for both" - So you should have two Adapters. Regarding `BaseAdapter` it is a base class for Adapters and comes with Android SDK. Whenever you need to implement a Adapter, you should extend this and implement those Abstract methods provided eg `GetView`. Are you quite new to Object Oriented programming?